# Linux file hierarchy - what's the best location to store lockfiles?

Tags: linux, directory-structure, synchronization, fhs, lock

I want to synchronize processes based on lock files (/ socket files). These files should only be removable by their creator user.

There are plenty of choices:

`/dev/shm`

`/var/lock`

`/run/lock`

`/run/user/<UID>`

`/tmp`

What's the best location for this purpose? And what way are above locations meant to be used for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. **`/dev/shm`** : It is nothing but implementation of traditional **shared memory** concept. It is an efficient means of passing data between programs. One program will create a memory portion, which other processes (if permitted) can access. This will result into speeding up things.
2. **`/run/lock`** (formerly `/var/lock`) [contains lock files](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLOCKLOCKFILES), i.e. files indicating that a shared device or other system resource is in use and containing the identity of the process (PID) using it; this allows other processes to properly coordinate access to the shared device.
3. **`/tmp`** : is the location for temporary files as defined in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), which is followed by almost all Unix and Linux distributions. Since RAM is significantly faster than disk storage, you can [use `/dev/shm` instead of `/tmp` for the performance boost](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html), if your process is I/O intensive and extensively uses temporary files.
4. **`/run/user/$uid`**: is created by [`pam_systemd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html) and used for storing files used by running processes for that user.

Coming to your question, you can definitely use `/run/lock` directory to store your lock file.

Comment: Note that `/run/` is non-portable - in case you like to use your software on other platforms tan Linux. UNIX uses `/var/lock/` or `/var/run/`.

Answer (score 2):

Make a directory under `/run/lock` and chmod it to 700, then create your lock files in there.

`/var/lock` on Linux Mint is a link to `/run/lock` (on Ubuntu, Linux Mint 17 and CentOS 7)

I would only store things under `/run/user/<UID>` if the processes only ever run while you are logged in.